# Can I pull data from a Google Sheet into inline text in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am creating exams for my students in Google Docs and would like to easily change the values and answer options without having to do all the math each time. I would like to have a google sheet where I can set the variables and have each possible multiple choice answer auto generated - and then be able to open a nicely formatted Google Doc where all these values automatically appear.

Answer (score 1):

This as easy as copying from Google Sheets and pasting in Google Docs, making sure that you "paste linked." It will paste as a table. When you change your sheets, an "update" button will appear on the Google Docs.

##### NOTE

The "paste linked" option is only available if pasting multiple cells.

If you need to paste a single linked cell, first paste it as part of 2 cell range, then edit the link using "Change Range" to limit it to the single cell.

Credit to [@Matěj-Kříž](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/180394/mat%C4%9Bj-k%C5%99%C3%AD%C5%BE) for this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: **NO, this is not possible**.

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment (02/2023). The main reason is that it does not go to insert the table inline into the text. Inline table is unsupported.

See the related question [How can I align a table so that text floats around it in Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74870/180394)